# Have user select StreamWriter filepath and name

Tags: vb.net, filepath, streamwriter, savefiledialog, streamwriter.write

I have a GUI where the user is capable of logging data that comes in from the serial port. I have it set up where I can specify the filename and path that the streamwriter uses in the code, but I would like to have the user select their own path and filename. I was thinking maybe something with the SaveFileDialogue, but I couldn't figure anything out. The file is simply being written as a .csv as well. Open to any suggestions!

My code for declaring the streamwriter is:

```
    Public Class ReadMeasuredValues
Dim sw as StreamWriter

    Private Sub startread_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartRead.Click
            sw = New StreamWriter(savefiledialog1.filename, False)

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        sw.WriteLine("Date, Time, Ch 1, Ch 2, Ch 3, Ch 4, Ch 5, Ch 6, Ch 7, Ch 8, Ch 9, Ch 10, Ch 11, Ch 12, Ch 13, Ch 14, Ch 15, Ch 16, Ch 17, Ch 18, Ch 19, Ch 20, Ch 21, Ch 22, Ch 23, Ch 24, Ch 25, Ch 26, Ch 27, Ch 28, Ch 29, Ch 30, Ch 31, Ch 32")
    End If
    End Sub
```

Code for launching the SaveFileDialog is

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV|*.csv"
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    savefiledialog1.showDialog()
                End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: [**How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please edit your question via the `Edit` button instead. It's almost impossible to read code in the comments.

Comment: my apologies. The code is in my edited question

Comment: What happened to your `SaveFileDialog` attempt? What you need to do is: **1)** Open the dialog via `ShowDialog()` and check the return value of it (`OK` = user chose to save the file). **2)** Initialize the `StreamWriter` passing the SaveFileDialog's `FileName` as file path. **3)** Write.

Comment: I've added the code for launching the dialog. I'd like to launch the dialog when the check box is checked and write one line to the streamwriter on a button press and then a set of lines on a timer interval

Comment: You are declaring a new `StreamWriter` in the check box. Move it out to _class level_ (outside any `Sub` or `Function`) so that you can access it from within your entire form instead.

Comment: If I do it that way, I can't have the filepath be `savedialog1.filename` because the filename will be blank and I won't be able to launch my form

Comment: Yes you can, if you wait with initializing the `StreamWriter` until you've closed the SFD.

Comment: Now how would I go about doing that?

Comment: My declaration is `dim sw as new StreamWriter(savefiledialog1.filename, false)`

Comment: You just wait with initializing the `StreamWriter` until you've closed the SFD. For example, class level: `Dim sw As StreamWriter` - after closing the SFD: `sw = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, False)`.

Comment: It breaks at this line `sw = New StreamWriter(savefiledialog1.FileName, False)` and I get the error that it's being used by another process

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's going on. Are you trying to overwrite a file?

Comment: If it exists, it should be overwritten, if not, it should be created. But I don't understand what other process could be using it

Comment: Can you modify it manually?

Comment: Yes, I can. The file will be created if it doesn't exist, as it should, but nothing is ever written due to the error

Comment: Can you update the question again with your latest code? Otherwise you can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to find which processes locks your file. Open Process Explorer and press CTRL + F, then type in the name of the file and it should display the process using it.

Comment: I don't see anything that should be a problem. Try Process Explorer and see what locks the file (also make sure it isn't your own app).

Comment: I also am using the StreamWriter to write to the same file in two different subs if that matters at all. Once on a button press and repeatedly on a timer tick

Comment: Reusing the very same `StreamWriter` doesn't matter, only opening two different ones and attaching them to the same file does.

Comment: Should I use the same line `sw = New StreamWriter(savefiledialog1.filename, False)` in both subs?

Comment: No :). Once you've called `New` you have initialized an instance of the `StreamWriter` which you can now use until you close it (or until it goes out of scope, but it won't do that in your class).

Comment: Calling `New StreamWriter` two times will result in creating two different `StreamWriter`s. The first one is replaced by the second one, but that doesn't mean that the first one has released its lock to the file.